# where is the definition of router in import router from "./router"

Tags: vue.js, bulma

Reference: [Bulma](https://github.com/troymott/bulma-book-code/tree/master/vuejs/src)

```
https://github.com/troymott/bulma-book-code/blob/master/vuejs/src/main.js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  render: h => h(App),
});

https://github.com/troymott/bulma-book-code/blob/master/vuejs/src/router/index.js

import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
...
import CustomerEdit from "../pages/CustomerEdit.vue";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: "/",
      redirect: '/login'
    },
...
  ],
  linkActiveClass: 'is-active' /* change to Bulmas active nav link */
});
```

Question> I am not able to find where the code defines the variable of router. May someone help point to me where the variable of `router` is defined within `router/index.js`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a variable or a function but an instance thats being passed from the `router/index.js`

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [{
      path: "/",
      redirect: '/login'
    },
...
  ],
  linkActiveClass: 'is-active' /* change to Bulmas active nav link */
});
```

is actually referenced by the variable `router` in main.js which is then used while creating the `vue` instance.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router, // place of usage
  render: h => h(App),
});
```

Comment: When I see `import ABC from "./ABC.vue", I always expect that "./ABC.vue" defines export default { name: 'ABC' }. It seems like this is not always case. Do you have reference link where I can read more regarding to the import syntax? Thank you

Comment: Check this out! https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/vue-js-routing-with-vue-router-4c428fabb078